# Displaying array in a table by the type of each element

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I have an array that looks like this,but with much more elements:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_name] => Pizza Craft
            [dependency] => 0
            [product_type] => 1
            [quantity] => 1
        )
)
```

In this array I have the products for a specif menu (the menu is different every day). The menu will be structured on 5 products type: main dish, trimmings, salad, soup, desert (in array, product_type from 1-5).

I want to display this in a table,structured on products types, from the main dish to the desert. I did this and it's working, but I want to know if it's a better way because I have too many foreach.
I'm using `unset($products[$key]);` after each `echo` for greater efficiency. This way, after I'm done with a product, I will remove it so the next foreach will not read previous products.
So, how can I display this more efficiently?

Note: I have a second array that's equal with the array from the db, so if I need to loop again, for some reason, throw the array, I will not do another request to the db.

Display Code:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Felul principal:</td>
                <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>
                    <?php if($product['product_type'] == 1):?>
                        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
                        <?php unset($products[$key]);?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garnitura:</td>
                <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>
                    <?php if($product['product_type'] == 2):?>
                        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
                        <?php unset($products[$key]);?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Salata:</td>
                <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>
                    <?php if($product['product_type'] == 3):?>
                        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
                        <?php unset($products[$key]);?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Supa:</td>
                <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>
                    <?php if($product['product_type'] == 4):?>
                        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
                        <?php unset($products[$key]);?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Desert:</td>
                <?php foreach($products as $key=>$product):?>
                    <?php if($product['product_type'] == 5):?>
                        <td><?php echo $product['product_name'];?></td>
                        <?php unset($products[$key]);?>
                    <?php endif;?>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query `ORDER BY product_type` and then in your loop you can check if it changes and display the new one.  I have not added the table HTML, but this is the basic process.  Instead of the `$product_types` array you could join a table that contains the `product_type` and the name of that product type.  Then that name would also be in each row of the `$products` array:

```
$product_types = array(1 => 'Felul principal', 2 => 'Garnitura'); //add the rest

$prev = 0;
foreach($products as $product):
    if($product['product_type'] != $prev):
        echo $product_types[$product['product_type']];
        $prev = $product['product_type'];
    }
    echo $product['product_name'];
}
```

Comment: Nice
Thank you very much

Comment: When adding html you need to check if it is the first product to know when to open and close your tr tags

Comment: @Echtniet It will be the first product when `$product['product_type'] != $prev`

Comment: Yes but what i mean is when it is the first product you need to open a tr, but for the rest of them you need to close the previous tr then open a new tr

Answer (score 1):

**Do u have product_type Master table ?**

if **yes** , You can finish ur problem with 2 loops

1. Loop You Can simple create a array from loop with **key** product_type name=> which will cover all related products as **array** in **value**
2. Loop for Making Html **Table**

Comment: Thank you.It's the same ideea as #AbraCadaver, but his answear it's more detailed

Comment: Your Loop will only work for 0 not for rest ,

Also Some time product type 1 will be displayed in 0 product type

Answer (score 0):

In this way the code is quite clean and functional:

```
<?php

    $productTypes = array(
        1 => 'Felul principal',
        2 => 'Garnitura',
        3 => 'Salata',
        4 => 'Supa',
        5 => 'Desert'
    );

    echo '<table>';

    foreach($productTypes as $type => $name){
        foreach($products as $product){
            if($product['product_type']==$type){
                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$name.':</td>
                        <td>'.$product['product_name'].'</td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }
        }
    }

    echo '</table>';

?>
```